# Rewrite directory names to php files with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically folder etc has files:

```
contact.php
help.php
news.php
```

How can I make `/etc/contact` direct to `/etc/contact.php`?

Comment: [Multiviews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html) should do this - can you enable it for that directory?

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php
```

Comment: The _condition_ `%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f` will never (very unlikely) be successful, since `REQUEST_URI` is a URL-path, not a file-path. It should be something like: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f` instead. (And you should also include the `L` flag on this rule.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the code below. first you need to head over to cPanel and in the directory, create a new .htaccess file or open for edit the one you already have, then insert the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

However, I still have issues with the PHP sections. for example, domain.com/dashboard now works but domain.com/dashboard/users still shows a 404 but when I manually enter domain.com/dashboard/?pg=users it works.