# URL Shows 404 but adding .php at the end displays

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have set up this website and it's working perfectly, however, extensions such as domain.com/dashboard will display a 404 but when I add .PHP at the back -> domain.com/dashboard.php it displays. Is there a way to make all the files display correctly without me adding .PHP at the end of each URL?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your server configuration.

Comment: Using the basic namecheap shared hosting with php7.4 as default

Comment: Please provide your actual configuration files, especially your rewrite rules.

Comment: I actually got to this to work. There was no .htaccess file so I created one and then added the following lines of code:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Comment: So, we can close this question as a duplicate to https://serverfault.com/questions/392821/rewrite-directory-names-to-php-files-with-htaccess

Comment: @Brun0L3z With your solution, try requesting `/dashboard/anything`. See the following related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Comment: thanks @MrWhite I did check the solution and tried applying it in my case as seen below

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

however, I still get the error of the second / so dashboard/anything gives a 404 and even /dashboard/ still gives a 404. Please help.

NOTE: I have read everything 4 times over at https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Comment: It is not normal behavior to redirect a request to `domain.com/dashboard` to `domain.com/dashboard.php` and I fear this could have unintended consequences. When a specific file is requested it should have it’s full name specified. If you request `domain.com/dashboard` then the assumption is that this is a directory and the server should look for a default file like `index.html`, `index.php`, etc. in that directory. What you describe happening is normal, expected behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewrite directory names to php files with htaccess?](https://serverfault.com/questions/392821/rewrite-directory-names-to-php-files-with-htaccess)